# Creating an installer for my Mac application

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker, dmg

I have this Mac application that consists of 2 files:

1. firstFile.tst
2. secondFile

I would like to put them in:

1. ~/Library/Audio/MyProg/
2. ~/Library/Application Support/MyProg/

I would also like the installer to look like them fancy DMG installers (like Skype's).
Now, I am a newbie when it comes to Mac but I am willing to learn whatever it takes.

I know the dmg installers are actually drags and drops; does that mean that if my application doesn't consist of a real application (it is a plug in - there's no shortcut to put in the Applications folder) then I can't do it?

I was thinking about calling the icon on the left MyProg and the icon on the right COMP_NAME and that dragging MyProg to COMP_NAME simply put the 2 files I described in the places I described for them.

Is there's any way to achieve this or should I just go with PackageMaker and drop the fancy dmg idea (I really like the fancy installers)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen several plugins like this that use PackageMaker, but wrap the package in a .dmg (that is, you mount the .dmg and all it has on it is a .pkg file).

Comment: Good idea! But what shortcuts do they use in the dmg? Where are they copying the pkg to?

Comment: And another thing: Who executes the .pkg file? I mean, all .dmg files can do is copy files from place to place...

Comment: The dmg has a .pkg on it when it mounts. The user has to double-click to install it.