# Create a DMG Installable for Mac OS

Tags: macos, applescript, dmg

I have to make a DMG installable,

I am able to make a Normal installables where it will have symbolic link to Application folder, and My App file,

I would like to create similar to Skype or Mozilla, where they drag an App icon to application file and possibly it copies certain file to /library/Application Support folder.

I have done it using Shell Script, some site says here is Apple script will come into the picture, but couldn't figure it out, how to make use of it.

Comment: The line starting with `user will allow` is confusing.   Do you want to create an installer package which will install the app to Applications and the "certain files" to `/Library/Application Support/App Name`?   Or do you want to create a DMG which contains the App and an installer package which will install the remaining pieces, so that the "certain files" installer package is optional?

Answer (score 0):

## Using the Installer

If you are not just doing a drag and drop install then the next most common thing is to create an [installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_%28OS_X%29) script and have the user click on that rather than running a shell script or an Apple script directly.

The application to create the `.pkg` files that the mac Installer application uses is called [PackageMaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackageMaker#PackageMaker), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9251991/1353098) for more information.

For more recent versions of Xcode it appears that PackageMaker is not available any more. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11487596/1353098) discusses it's replacement, the Xcode "Build and Archive" target and using it to create a *component package*. The [chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11487658/1353098) discusses creating the appropriate target in Xcode and using it to build your `.pkg` file for installation.

## Drag and Drop

An alternative is instead to use a standard *drag and drop* install and then create the configuration files when the application is first run. I believe that Firefox uses a similar approach to this to create the profile that the user uses when they first run the application.

Comment: yeah, i was using package maker, but it seems its not coming along with XCode 4.5 onwards

Comment: It seems not. I guess this is because Apple want you to use the AppStore for any non-drag'n'drop applicaitons.

Comment: @Amitg2k12 I have updated the answer to reference this problem and link to the solution.